# getting an error for trying to add prefix to discord bot

Tags: c#, dsharp+

when trying to make a simple discord bot using dsharpplus i get an error saying "Cannnot Implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable" on line 26

this is my code here:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // makes a token for the bot
        string prefix = "!";
        string token = "";
        var discord = new DiscordClient(new DiscordConfiguration()
        {
  
            Token = token,
            TokenType = TokenType.Bot,
            Intents = DiscordIntents.AllUnprivileged
        });
        // responds to commands
        discord.UseCommandsNext(new CommandsNextConfiguration
        {
            StringPrefixes = prefix,
            EnableDms = false,
            EnableMentionPrefix = true
        });
    }
```

i have DSharpPlus and DSharpPlus.CommandsNext in my code

Comment: as per the docs stringprefixes is a list of strings https://dsharpplus.github.io/api/DSharpPlus.CommandsNext.CommandsNextConfiguration.html#DSharpPlus_CommandsNext_CommandsNextConfiguration_StringPrefixes

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to assign a string `prefix` to an enumerable of strings `StringPrefixes`. You could put your `prefix` in a list, or any other object with its type implementing `IEnumerable<string>`, and then assign that to the `StringPrefixes` property:

```
List<string> prefixes = new List<string>();
prefixes.Add(prefix);
StringPrefixes = prefixes;
```

or shorter:

```
StringPrefixes = new List<string>{ prefix };
```